# Different versions of the same dll in one application c#

Tags: c#, module-build

We are currently migrating legacy application from VS2003 .Net 1.1 Windows application to ASP.NET MVC Web Application.
Client is going to move from Windows 7 to Windows 10 OS for all system.

Temporarily compile  / run legacy windows application from VS2003 .Net 1.1 to VS2012 .Net 2.0 in Windows 10 OS.

We have tried many time to fix the below error in VS2012 .Net 2.0 as possible:

```
An assembly with the same simple name 
'Interop.VRDPLAYERLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. 
Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side.
```

PublicKeyToken is null for Interop.VRDPLAYERLib.dll version V1.1.4322 & V2.0.50727

In Legacy Windows Application Snip Code:

```
VRDPlayer.ocx | File Type: ActiveX
VRDPlayer.Register("VRDPlayer.ocx");
....
MethodBuilder meb;
meb.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.PreserveSig | meb.GetMethodImplementationFlags());
```

Can you please suggest / help us to fix this error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: its saying exactly what the problem is, you are trying to load the same dll again. if you don't understand what that means, then that is what you should be googling.

Comment: @seabizkit : We have search related to this error. But for us PublicKeyToken is null for both version.

Comment: I am not sure what you are telling me...`PublicKeyToken is null for both version` what has that got to do with it? who care what the PublicKeyToken is your still attempting to load it twice by the sounds of the error.. maybe supply the minimal repeatable example to show case your error